# RectTransform coordinates according to TextMesh Pro text size

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, scripting, transform

I'm trying to create an InputField (TextMesh Pro) with a dynamic (its text content may vary) prefix.
This spectacular image should explain the goal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/97agV.jpg

So I set a TextMeshPro text to use as Prefix, and by script I was trying to "move" the TextArea accordingly.
The fact is, TextArea is a RectTransform, and I'm operating in a ScreenSpace render mode.

I was trying like this:

```
private TextMeshProGUI prefix;
private RecTransform textArea;


public void ChangePrefixTo(string newPrefix)
{
    float oldWidth = prefix.preferredWidth;

    prefix.text = newPrefix;
    float newWidth = prefix.preferredWidth;

    Vector2 newPos = new Vector2();
    newPos.x = textArea.position.x + (newWidth - oldWidth);
    newPos.y = textArea.position.y;

    textArea.position = newPos;
}
```

, but the textArea gets shot into the stars.
How can I map the RectTransform position according to the size of a TextMeshPro text?

Thanks for the help and long live the whales

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a script to resize your prefix, you can group both of your elements in a Horizontal Layout Group, check only *Width* for Child Controls Size.

Add a Layout Element and set your Preferred Width to define the size of your TextArea.

The Prefix will scale according to his content, and it will push your text area as it grows.

Comment: Fancy. I owe you a beer.

Comment: Anytime for the beer! :)
If it's working for you, you can mark the answer as accepted, it might help others. Thanks!

Comment: Demo is changed to private, please edit or find another way to publish it.